# Boto3 list all Security Groups attached to all ELBs

Tags: aws-sdk, boto3, amazon-elb, aws-security-group

I am trying to list all Security Groups that are assigned to ELBs in an AWS account. This is where I'm at right now:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
region_list = [region['RegionName'] for region in ec2.describe_regions()['Regions']]
for region in region_list:
    elb_client = boto3.client('elbv2', region_name=region)
    elbs = elb_client.describe_load_balancers()
    for elb in elbs['LoadBalancers']:
        print(elb['SecurityGroups']
```

But I'm getting:

> print (elb['SecurityGroups'])
>   KeyError: 'SecurityGroups'

Which is strange considering I know the key exists as per:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_load_balancers

If I change the key to, say **LoadBalancerArn** it works without any problems. One thing to consider is that LoadBalancerArn returns a single string, while SecurityGroups is a nested list, but I think I would be getting a different type of error if that was the problem.

Can someone help me with this?

**Solution:**
The initial code didn't work since some ELBs were not assigned to SGs. The key check below fixes this.

```
    for elb in elbs['LoadBalancers']:
    try:
        value = elb['SecurityGroups']
        print(elb['SecurityGroups'])
    except KeyError:
            # Key is not present
            pass
```

Comment: The first step to debugging this would be to try printing `elb` to see what you are working with, or setting a breakpoint in your code and examining the `elb` object. My first guess is that you may have an ELB without any security groups assigned, so the `SecurityGroups` property is null or absent.

Comment: Hi Mark, I thought about that already and I added a conditional True evaluation on the property, which resulted in the same thing. Additionally, priting elb returns all properties under the LoadBalancer list as expected.

Comment: Please include the output from printing `elb` in your question.

Comment: Hi Mark, it appears you were right all along. I just needed to do a key exists check like. I've updated the question with the answer. Thank you for helping out!